# iptables rules - input and output

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I'm new with Linux and `iptables`. I have a Ubuntu Server distro (12.04) on a PC which has 2 network interfaces (`eth0` and `eth1`). I also have 2 laptops, one is plugged to `eth0` and the other to `eth1`.

laptop1 ipconfig: 172.16.221.120 - 255.255.252.0 
laptop2 ipconfig: 192.168.222.250 - 255.255.255.0

I want to ping the laptop2 from laptop1 successfully.

Do I have to create `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` rules? Or a `FORWARD` rule, too?

I've tried this with no success:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tcpdump` in order to find out how far your pings come:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n icmp
tcpdump -i eth1 -n icmp
```

Furthermore it's not enough to allow pings on the server; the laptops must be configured so that they know they can reach the other one via the server (routing).

Probably your firewall has a rule which allows packets which are a reply. If not then you also need

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

which makes sense anyway as you probably want to allow both laptops to ping the other one. You may limit this to pings and pongs, though:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

The last problem is the laptops themselves: If at least one of them has its own firewall then it may block pings (in general or due to the source address outside the interfaces network).

Answer (score 0):

By default, you do not need any rules as the netfilter chains are empty with an `ACCEPT` default policy. If you have added rules already, then to allow the ping through will need rules added to the `FORWARD` chain.

You will also need to set up the server as a router and make sure each laptop has the server as it's default route (or at least have a route for the other laptop's subnet).

To enable routing (IP forwarding), you need to set `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to `1`. Ubuntu should have `/etc/sysctl.conf` where you can set up items in `/proc/sys` automatically:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

If you do change this, you will need to load the changes into the kernel:

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The change will automatically be loaded on next boot so you only need to run this command manually once after changing `/etc/sysctl.conf`.